# SQL ORDER BY by inside ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access

Trying to get a grip on SQL

I'd like to order by date and then inside that, order by title.

Example:

```
SELECT *
FROM tblboek
ORDER BY jr_van_uitgave DESC
```

How do I order by title inside the order by age?

Comment: MySQL and Access, that's a very unusual combination... (Don't tag products not involved!)

Comment: If you want to `ORDER BY` something else, then why is your title about `GROUP BY`??. Anyway, just add the other column to the `ORDER BY`: `ORDER BY jr_van_uitgave DESC, age`

Comment: Jarlh, I tagged it because I am doing mySQL inside access directly on top of the collums and tables, if that makes sense.

Comment: It doesn't really. You are probably confusing using SQL (the language) with MySQL (a RDBMS)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM tblboek 
ORDER BY age,   -- First order by age
         title  -- if ages are the same, order by title
```

Add `DESC` whenever you need it, e.g. if you want to order by age in descending order:

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM tblboek 
ORDER BY age desc,  
         title
```